# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@sveltejs/kit' imported from /var/task/.svelte-kit/vercel-tmp/index.js

Tags: vercel, sveltekit

I'm trying to deploy a sveltekit app to vercel with `adapter-vercel`. It's just a basic SPA app.

I've created a sveltekit app with:

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "playwright test",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-check": "^2.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vitest": "^0.25.3"
}
```

svelte.config.js

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import vercel from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel';



/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: vercel({

        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

When I try to deploy to vercel I am greeted with these messages in the Functions tab:

```
undefined   ERROR   Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@sveltejs/kit' imported from /var/task/.svelte-kit/vercel-tmp/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:865:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:958:20)
    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:909:12)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1173:79)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
RequestId: 1aff6783-3836-446a-99a9-2741ab5175a5 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

These are my settings in Vercel:

```
Build Command:    npm run build

Output Directory: build

Install command: npm install

Development command:
```

I have tested the following things:

I used to have in package.json this:

```
"@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "next",
```

Changed to this:

```
"@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "^1.0.0",
```

I added this to the root layout:

```
export const ssr = false;
```

Comment: I haven't encountered this myself, so I'm just guessing: [Did you create the project a while back so that Node 14 is being used?](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-vercel#node-version)

Comment: The project is created very recently and on my machine I have v18.0.0.0.

Comment: I am having this issue as well... very frustrating

Comment: I am having this issue too

Comment: @sander - were you able to resolve this, I am facing same issue now!

Answer (score 4):

For anybody looking, I found the answer to this here:
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6988

Essentially, remove `/.vercel` from your repo and add it to `.gitignore`

I don't know why this isn't added to the documentation in either Vercel or SvelteKit